# Limit External API Calls From Plugin In Craft 2

Tags: database, craft2, limit, api

I have a plugin in Craft 2 that will make an API call to an external API to gather and display data on a template; however, I would like to limit the number of calls to a certain number per second (or to sleep for a set number of milliseconds).

I have found some examples of PHP code that do this; however, they usually require a database table or flat file to reference the count.  I was wondering if there is anything Craft-centric that might exist which would assist in this, or if this would be more a case of using pure PHP code in the plugin to connect to the db and to query the db in assistance to setting the limit?
Thanks for any leads